# MySql Config error

Tags: mysql, innodb

Have a Wordpress website running on Digital Ocean. This morning began receiving "Error establishing a database connection" message. Droplet is a 2 GB Memory / 40 GB HD running Ubuntu 14.04.

Tried restarting mysql, but get "Job Failed to Start".

Status reports "mysql stopped/waiting"

Help me anyone please.
Additionally I do not know how to set up SWAP.

```
170125 7:51:17 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete 
170125 7:51:18 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will 
170125 7:51:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. Th/usr/sbin/m.jsqld: Can't find file: 1./mysql/plugin.frml (errno: 13) 
170125 7:51:18 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it. 
170125 7:51:18 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled 
170125 7:51:18 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 
170125 7:51:18 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8 
170125 7:51:18 InnoDB: Using Linux native RIO 
170125 7:51:18 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12 
170125 7:51:18 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 
170125 7:51:18 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool 
170125 7:51:18 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error. 
170125 7:51:18 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed 
170125 7:51:18 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB 
170125 7:51:18 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Error log is attached [image: errorlog]

Comment: This is not a programming question and is a better fit on the [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) site. Additionally, do try and post textual errors or logs as plain text in the body of your question. Screenshots like this can be very hard for people to read.

Comment: What else are you running in that tiny droplet?  Let's see your my.cnf.  Did you recently upgrade mysql/mariadb?